# Move from a stored procedure based site to an ADO.NET entity framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been working on a website that has been up for 18 years.

Currently whenever we want to write methods to call information out of the database we have to create multiple methods and a stored procedure to convert into an object.

```
  private static DataTable GetAddress(int ownerId)
    {
        using (var sql = SqlWrapper.CreateOrUpdateWrapper(AdapterType.SqlCommand, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Address_LoadById"))
        {
                sql.AddParameterWithValue("@id", ownerId, SqlDbType.Int);

            sql.Open();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sql.ExecuteReader());
            return dt;


        }
    }

   private static List<Address> LoadAddressesByItemId(int ownerId, bool loadContact)
    {

        List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        var dt = GetAddress(ownerId);
        if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return addresses;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            addresses.Add(new Address(dr, loadContact));
        }

        return addresses;
    }

  private Address(DataRow dr, bool getContact = true)
    {

        AddressID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["AddressID"]);
        AddressType = (AddressTypes)(Convert.ToInt32(dr["addressType"]));
        AddressLineOne = dr.GetString("addressLine1");
        AddressLineTwo = dr.GetString("addressLine2");
        AddressLineThree = dr.GetString("addressLine3");
        Town = dr.GetString("town");
        County = dr.GetString("County");
        Country = dr.GetString("Country");
        PostCode = dr.GetString("Postcode");
        OwnerId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["OwnerId"]);
    }
```

Personally I find this rather long and would like to move over to the entity framework. Like below.

```
   public static List<Address> GetAddressesByID(int ownerId)
    {
        return DBContext.Addresses.Where(a => a.OwnerId == ownerId).ToList();
    }
```

how would I go about doing this, the class library is 200+ classes. So I would like to only convert classes over to use EF only when writing new code for that class or one that links into it.

For the above example I want to leave the Owner class alone using the existing stored procedure code and update Addresses so it is using entity framework and Linq.

Does anyone know of a way to start using EF 6 mid project and only applying EF6 to new classes and old classes when required without editing the entire class library.

Comment: No one can answer this without any code and some more background information. Also it is very hard to answer this without an example that one can use to create an exemplary solution. Please add this information and at least some formatting to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we faced similar situation , To call Stored Procedures for query operations you can use SqlQuery in Entityframework which is very helpful

```
_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<EntityType>("sp_name",parameters).ToList();
```

For Executenonquery Operations(Transactions) you can use

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
                        @"UPDATE tblname SET Rating = 5" + 
                            " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'" 
                        );
```

Please note that _dbContext object of your Context class inherits from DbContext Class of Entityframework